# Error Message "Perhaps you intended to use TemplateHaskell "

Tags: haskell

I tried to use to infix expression for div function as follows:

```
92 'div' 10
```

---

The following error message popped out:
Syntax error on 'div'
Perhaps you intended to use TemplateHaskell
In the Template Haskell Quotation 'div'

Comment: Despite being a simple typographical error this error message doesn't point to it.  This question should stay as that error message is searchable and is useful to others.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those look like quotes (') and not back ticks (`) to me, which is why the compiler is confused.  The infix expression uses the back ticks (left of 1 on most keyboards).